# Как сравнить две строки без учета регистра, знаков препинания и пробелов?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, строки, oracle

В условии `WHERE` необходимо сравнить две строки, чтобы условие равенства выполнялось без учета регистра, знаков препинания и пробелов, т.е.:

```
1w:2 Q.=1w2q
```

---

PS Oracle, без программных расширений.

Comment: Попробуйте перед этим убрать запятые, пробелы и тд.

Comment: спасибо, кэп ((

Comment: Я имел ввиду программно. Например, потом сравнить строки where Как ДеЛа = КАКДЕЛА or какдела.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.. where upper(replace(s1, '.,: ')) = upper(replace(s2, '.,: '))

Comment: Хотя так выбирается последовательность символов '.,: ', а не каждый символ в отдельности. Правильнее будет так:
REGEXP_REPLACE(upper(s1),'[[:punct:][:space:]]','')

Comment: ну да, пардон

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```sql
select src, res 
from ( 
    select src, regexp_replace (src, '[[:punct:][:space:]]+') res 
    from (
        select '1w:2 Q.=1w2q' src from dual test_strings)
) where lower (res) = '1w2q1w2q' and upper (res) = '1W2Q1W2Q';


SRC          RES             
------------ ----------------
1w:2 Q.=1w2q 1w2Q1w2q
```